# Bind List within List to DataGrid

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have class A Collection

In Class A I have class b collection

Now I want to bind Class b property to gridview with use of C# binding syntax without write any code in code behind item or in gridview event

can any buddy help me.

## Problem

i have a list "A" which have a list "B" within it and B have a property C now i want to bind C

means i will bind A as datasource to grid  and for column i want "B[0].C

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
GridView1.DataSource = A;


<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
<Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# ((YourCollectionType)Eval("B"))[0].C %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```